# When is Kleisli category regular?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Are there any known conditions on the monad $\mathbb{T}$, such that $\mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{T}}$ (in particular when $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{Set}$) is regular?

Comment: Do you have any non-trivial examples in mind?